# CompactDatabase with dbEncrypt returns "3001: Invalid argument" error

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2010, ms-jet-ace, compact-database

I am getting a `3001: Invalid argument` error when trying:

`DbEngine.CompactDatabase "db1.accdb", "db2.accdb", , dbEncrypt`

I believe the function is using `ACEDAO.DLL` version 14.0.6016.1000

What could be the cause of the error?   It only seems to happen with `dbEncrypt`.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the article referred to in Remou's answer, `dbEncrypt` requires a password:

```
CompactDatabase firstdb, seconddb, ";pwd=secret", dbEncrypt
```

It also seems that an upgrade can't be done in the same call, thus I needed two lines to upgrade an older `MDB` to an encrypted `ACCDB`. Note the placement of the password in each line:

```
CompactDatabase oldMDB, encryptedDb, ";pwd=secret", dbEncrypt
CompactDatabase encryptedDb, upgradedDb, , dbVersion120, ";pwd=secret"
```

The following did not work and gave the `Invalid argument` error:

`CompactDatabase oldMDB, encryptedAccdb, ";pwd=secret", dbEncrypt + dbVersion120`

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely to be the password: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/et-EE/accessdev/thread/317b025c-07ff-4c84-883f-5f602e88af9d

```
DbEngine.CompactDatabase "db1.accdb", "db2.accdb", ";pwd=apass"
```

When db2.accdb is opened, Decrypt database is an option.